# How to add data in columns in MySQL but some strings are already set?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I'm creating a program where I should save data on database. I have two frames but only using one table in one database and on the first frame I already saved data on row 1-6. Now on the second frame I want to add data on row 7-12 only. How can I do this? Or should I make another table instead?

I'm newbie to Java, so help would be great.

Here's my code for the save:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Save this input?", "Confirm", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    strCountry = txtCountry.getText();
    strMembers = txtareaMembers.getText();
    strSong = txtSong.getText();
    strAlbum = txtAlbum.getText();
    Concert = (String) cmbConcerts.getSelectedItem();
    Biblio = (String) cmbBiblio.getSelectedItem();

    btnSubFirst.setEnabled(false);
    btnSubPrev.setEnabled(false);
    btnSubNext.setEnabled(true);
    btnSubLast.setEnabled(true);
    btnSubEdit.setEnabled(false);
    btnSubSave.setEnabled(false);
    btnSubCancel.setEnabled(true);
    txtCountry.setEditable(false);
    txtSong.setEditable(false);
    txtAlbum.setEditable(false);

    SaveData();
public void SaveData() {
    try {
        String strQuery = "INSERT INTO tblband(bandname,label,genre,year,member,album,country,members,song,recent,concert,biblio)" + "VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banddb", "root", "");
        st = con.prepareStatement(strQuery);
        st.setString(1, strBand);
        st.setString(2, strRecord);
        st.setString(3, Genre);
        st.setString(4, Year);
        st.setString(5, Member);
        st.setString(6, Album);
        st.setString(7, strCountry);
        st.setString(8, strSong);
        st.setString(9, strAlbum);
        st.setString(10, Concert);
        st.setString(11, Biblio);
        st.setString(12, strMembers);
        st.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is successfully inserted into database.");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in submitting data." + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: your **INSERT INTO** statement, only include the columns you want to insert into (7-12 headings) not (1-12). You might also need to add in the row you want to insert them into (instead of creating a new row)- so include a **where** clause

Comment: Should I change the INSERT INTO a SELECT * FROM? or I can just retain it?

Comment: INSERT should be ok, but an UPDATE query may also be what you're looking for: (See my answer below)

Comment: Bottom of this page: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: oh by the way, in this code I already just typed the columns where I'm gonna insert data, but what parameter should I use? 1-6 or 7-12?

Comment: include whichever column names you want to update (in a particular order), then in your values bit add the values (in order) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an update query:

*The UPDATE statement is used to update existing records in a table.*

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

A working example of this can be found: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

**Notice the WHERE clause in the SQL UPDATE statement!**

The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

Comment: instead of setting values like ContactName='Alfred Schmidt', how do I set the value from a jtextfield?